# SQL Server STUFF String Concat Slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is there any alternative to the SQL Server `STUFF` function?

I am developing a Windows Service that loops over a database and does some data processing, but the step of fetching data is extremely slow.

I have these tables

- `Sensors` table that define sensors config
- `Items` table that records each item information from devices
- `Itemdata` table that stores sensor values for each item row, so `Itemdata` table is linked to `Sensors` and `Items` tables

I need to select data from items  with grouping itemsdata as col like this

```
 1=5|2=6|
```

I use this T-SQL - it's working fine, but it's slow with more than 200,000 rows.

Without it, exec is extremely fast

With actual execution plan it take 99% in the `stuff` function:

[image]

I am using the following TSQL

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

IF (@dtFrom IS NOT NULL  AND @dtTo IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN -- with both dates
    SELECT
        m.itemsId,
        m.ObjectId,
        0 AS [type],
        STUFF((SELECT
                  (CAST(Sensors.SourceNameId AS nvarchar(10)) + '=' + CAST(t.Value AS nvarchar(20)) + '|')
               FROM [tavl2].[tavl].[itemsData] t WITH (NOLOCK)
               LEFT JOIN tavl2.tavl.Sensors WITH (NOLOCK) ON t.SensorsId = Sensors.SensorsId
               WHERE t.itemsId = m.itemsId
               FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 0, '') AS params
    FROM 
        tavl.[items] m WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        m.ObjectId = @objId
        AND m.GpsTime BETWEEN @dtFrom AND @dtTo
        AND m.Valid = 1; 
END
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: While it no doubt is slow, you cannot use the actual number from the execution plan when having XML in it (and even without - the numbers are guidelines). You need to access statistics for actual numbers. However, I have some difficulty seeing why you're concatenating the data in the database instead of your service layer as it seems more like presentation than query data?

Comment: i am using a concatenating to reduce amount of Loops And data  , as each item may have 10 itemdata and each query may have 200,000 item so it will be 200,000*10  Loop to concatenating

Comment: You're definitely not reducing loops by concatenating in this manner and the amount of data seems to not be a factor as you select the same data out and which seem to be rather minor data. Iterating over 200.000 rows in code should not be an issue compared to what you're trying to achieve in the database  - especially when doing something like this. SQL is a relational database, and when not using that aspect (set based operations), you're 9 times out of 10 better off doing your work elsewhere.

Comment: i dont select the same amount , i select only from item table , that 200,000 row for example , and use the itemdata table to provide me an extra col for sensor values , i believe that  doing this in sql server better than looping 2000000 + memory and io process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Managed to do it using **SQLCLR** ,

Here is an open-source CLR That do it in a very fast time

[GROUP_CONCAT string aggregate for SQL Server (hosted at codeplex)](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/documentation)